# Finding stores with non-zero stock

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Given the table below and a list of `ItemID`s, how do I find all `StoreID`s where `StockQty > 0` for all items in the list?

In the example below, given `ItemID` 5 and 6 I want the result to be 1. `ItemID` 5 would result in 1 and 2.

```
StoreID | ItemID | StockQty
---------------------------
 1      | 5      |  3       
 1      | 6      |  3       
 2      | 5      |  3       
 2      | 6      |  0       
 3      | 5      |  0       
 3      | 3      |  3
```

Comment: which RDBMS are you using? Please tag it

Comment: MS SQL 2012. Tagged!

Comment: please share your expected result

Comment: @TheGameiswar result for input of list with values 5,6 is 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would solve it like this:

The important part is the `HAVING`. It's basically just counting ItemIDs where the `StockQty` is 0.

Logic:
If `StockQty` of the item is > 0, i "count" it as 0, else as 1.
If `SUM` of those values is 0, all ItemIDs have a StockQty bigger than 0.

```
    SELECT StoreID
      FROM yourtable
     WHERE ItemID IN (5,6) -- your list of Items
  GROUP BY StoreID
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN StockQty > 0 THEN 0
                    ELSE 1
                END
               ) = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

For a table of items

```
 declare @List table(item int);
 insert  @List(item)
 values (5),(6);

 SELECT StoreID, Count(*)
 FROM yourtable t
 JOIN @List l ON t.ItemID = l.item AND StockQty > 0
 GROUP BY StoreID
 HAVING Count(*) = (SELECT count(*) FROM @List)
```

Comment: interesting solution